# Amazon EC2 EBS - can't locate data?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm having troubles understand Elastic Block Storage...

Last month I set up my first EC2 instance, I know that I will eventually use EC2 for my production site.

I grabbed the Ubuntu official AMI and used that, and then installed Aegir and Drupal on the server. This all got installed to `/var/aegir`.

Then I found out that if I were to stop the server there is a possibility that I might lose my data. Anyway, I took that change and rebooted (I was still learning and testing), and then when the server came back up, the data was all still there. I had lost my public DNS, but I was able to reconfigure that, and decided to use an Elastic IP address, then I set up an A record on a domain to point to this IP. (I assume that is the best way).

But now, I want to be able to create snapshots of my data and make sure that I am not losing any of my mySQL tables and database content. But when I create a snapshot, then create a volume of this snapshot and mount it to a brand new instance, I can't find any of the data at all?

The volume is mounted, but where is the data? How is it possible that I can't find the data, yet if I stop the instance and restart it, the original instance still has all the data in tact. That must mean that it is using EBS right? Which means creating a snapshot will copy that data.

Where am I going wrong, and how can I know what is in my snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

Try just creating an instance based on the snapshot without any additional mounting of volumes.  All should be well.